# Unable to find local grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have grunt running this just fine locally, however after setting up my Jenkins server to do the same thing I'm running into a problem with grunt being unable to find the grunt file. Could I have missed installing/configuring something? I can't tell what's wrong from the error output, here is what i'm getting on the jenkins box:

[user@buildserver]# ls

```
AUTHORS  CHANGELOG  coverage  Gruntfile.js  package.json  README.md  reports  spec  src
```

[user@buildserver]# grunt

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.6)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

Here's the Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine : {
      src : 'src/**/*.js',
      options : {
        specs : 'spec/**/*.js',
        template : require('grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul'),
        templateOptions: {
          coverage: 'reports/coverage.json',
          report: 'reports/coverage'
        }
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jasmine']);
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you installed grunt in your Jenkins server?

```
npm install grunt
```

Comment: I did, but I used -g which I guess was the wrong thing to do? I just did npm install grunt (without the -g) and it works now!

Comment: @Hoofamon according to version 0.4 you have to use global `grunt-cli` and local `grunt` http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Answer (score 2):

you can setup everything from jenkins admin interface, you don't need to install grunt locally :)

### Install Jenkins Plugins

- Git Plugin - *for git*
- Git Client Plugin - *for git*
- Git Parameter Plugin - *for git tags*
- GitHub API Plugin - *for github*
- NodeJS Plugin - *integration for common javascript tools NodeJS & npm*

### Git / Ant / Maven / NodeJS Installations

- Goto SERVER/jenkins/configure

Git

- Git -> Git installations -> Add Git -> JGit
- Git plugin -> Global Config user.name Value = "Anthony Mckale", Global Config user.email Value = "anthony.mckale@bskyb.com"

NodeJS

- NodeJS- > NodeJS installations -> Add NodeJS -> Name = "NodeJS 0.11.10", tick "Install automatically", select "Install from nodejs.org", add "grunt-cli" to globally installed packages

### TADA

and hopefully git/nodejs and grunt will be available to you

see the plugin wiki for more details how to add the grunt/node tasks to the jenkins job -> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

it's really easy :)

no ssh loggin required just jenkins admin rights